# Assign same variable name inside __init__() as in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, class, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I have defined as follows:

```
parameters = dict{a=1,b=2,c=3}
```

Now I have a class which will initialize this dictionary parameters and use the values as:

```
class test_class:

    def __init__(self,parameters):
        self.a=parameters['a']
        self.b=parameters['b']
        self.c=parameters['c']
```

The thing is my dictionary has a lot of entries and these entries will change depending upon how I define the dictionary. Is there a way I can loop over names and values over the dictionary inside the init function to assign the values as I have shown?

Comment: Why not just have the whole dictionary as a member of `test_class`?

Comment: just edited. the dictionary entry will change depending upon what I want.

Comment: What do you mean by that? You want `test_class` to have members that can vary from one instance to another?

Comment: yes. is that a bad thing? Currently what I am running requires only 3 members (as shown in the dictionary). The test_class can run on more members as well but I have accounted for them if I don't define them. In future, I have to add more entries to the dictionaries as I get them.

Comment: Yes, I would consider that a bad thing. It's easy to understand how to use `test_class` if you know every instance of it has the same members. If instances all potentially have different members, you'd need to check if an instance has a member before you can use it, and that would be needlessly messy. If you're handling variable amounts of information, it's best to use an object meant for that purpose, like a dictionary. Else, you're just reinventing the wheel and treating your class like a pseudo-dictionary, when you could just use a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use `setattr` in a loop to add new atributes to the class:

```
class test_class:
    def __init__(self, params):
        for k, v in params.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

tc = test_class({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3})
print(tc.a, tc.b, tc.c)
```

> 1 2 3